# How to upload image to cloudinary from node.js@heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, cloudinary

How to upload image from node.js on heroku (no permission to write to disk) to cloudinary using multer? Is is possible to upload the buffer object from memoryStorage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a few days I figure out how to do it! You'll need to use https://github.com/heldr/datauri to encode the buffer into data URI. here's what it looks like:

```
var Datauri = require('datauri');
var multer = require('multer');
var memoryStorage = multer.memoryStorage();
var memoryUpload = multer({
 storage: memoryStorage,
 limits: {fileSize: 500000, files: 1}
}).single('image');

cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: '',
  api_key: '',
  api_secret: ''
});
var dUri = new Datauri();

...

dUri.format(path.extname(req.file.originalname).toString(),req.file.buffer);
cloudinary.uploader.upload(dUri.content, function (err, i) {
  if (err) {
    ...
  } else {
    ...
  }
});
```

Comment: why is there  a : .toString()  i the first parameter ?